# Unresolved reference but compiles

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

I am running into a weird issue for severals days. My code is totally compiling and working but I have two kotlin objects (not class) flagged red as unresolved reference in my code. They are in different folder path, there is other kotlin objects in these paths totally working.

I use android studio 4.1.3, my kotlin plugin is up to date, I am using kotlin 1.4.32 and use these plugins in my build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'
```

I have absolutly no idea of what is going on, someone can help me?

Thanks

Comment: did you clean/rebuild and invalidate caches?

Comment: @tyczj sure, I even removed .android folder, all build files etc

Comment: Can you root and app level build.gradle and class that is shown as red?

Comment: @AleksanderMielczarek Sorry I don't get what you want me to do ?

Comment: just use 1.4.31 instead. it works on my case.

Comment: @mingchen it works thanks, so it is a kotlin bug.